Dormant account: Developer account is not in use (1 day left)
Problem " Developer account is at risk of being closed (1 day away)
If you plan to publish or maintain apps in the future, prevent your account from being closed by completing the following tasks:
If you haven’t done so yet, verify your email address and phone number on the Account details page.
Create and publish an app, or publish an update to an existing app on Google Play. Learn more "
PS : My account is verified
I saw late that my account would be deactivated if I did not submit an app or an app update. I have one day left. I sent the update, but the notification that my account might be deactivated tomorrow is still there. Is it enough that I sent the update, or does it need to be approved? Is there anything else I can do to prevent my account from being closed?

I would assume, that this is enough for the account not to be disabled, but if I were you I would make screenshots of everything and enable you to contact support if your account is suspened (with prrof of ownership). I am sure that the account is not scrapped immediately and rather is disabled.
